# CSS Background does not change after clicking on link

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a ruby on rails application. When clicking on a link which leads to a different page, where no background is set for the body element, the background does not change. It does however if you reload the new page.

I tried overwriting the background image on the new page which the link leads to, but that didn't help either.

All Code can be found [here](https://github.com/Malaber/condolence_book) but the links I am talking about are for example `<a href="<%= articles_list_path %>">Inhaltsverzeichnis</a>` [github](https://github.com/Malaber/condolence_book/blob/53598dfaf4fef04cae11b8b75256e3cdadc4c717/app/views/partials/_article_navbar.html.erb#L10). The CSS I am talking about is

```
body {
    background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'background.jpg' %>);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

in the corresponding [view](https://github.com/Malaber/condolence_book/blob/53598dfaf4fef04cae11b8b75256e3cdadc4c717/app/views/articles/show.html.erb#L5). It isn't included in the DOM if you click on the link, but is still is shown in browser.

The current master branch is also deployed [here](https://condolence-pascal.malaber.de/).
If you go onto that page and click on "Inhaltsverzeichnis" in the Navbar in the top left of the page you go to a new page and the background image stays. If you now reload the page the background image will vanish and the site looks like it should.

Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong? It looks to me as if the site somehow gets cached incorrectly or something.

Also, the problem only occurs if you click on the links within the page, if you type the url yourself, the page loads correctly in the first place.

Thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: Hi Malaber, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [ask] with [mcve]. Add the necessary code in the question instead of providing a link to github

Comment: Hey @sagar-v, I read it, but since I don't know what the problem is, I don't really know what code I should provide.I added the code from the github links to the question itself though. I think it is just a configuration issue, but I don't know. I guess I can try building a reprex but still I don't know which files to include here and which not as I have no clue where the problem is.

Comment: What happens when you add `background:none` for `body` in https://github.com/Malaber/condolence_book/blob/53598dfaf4fef04cae11b8b75256e3cdadc4c717/app/views/articles/list.html.erb

Comment: To address your question, you're setting a background image for body tag from one page and then navigate to other page without reloading browser. The new page doesn't have any style description for body tag. Hence browser use the old one from cache.

Comment: It changes the behaviour but it doesn't fix the problem. It now removes the background correctly when clicking on the link. But when I click on the link to the main page, now the main page has no background until I reload that page.

Comment: Can you build and deploy the new one?

Comment: I just deployed it. Thank you for troubleshooting btw!

Comment: The problem is, when you navigate to the sublink, it adds a new `style` tag to the dom and it doesn't get removed when you navigate back. To repro, go to the website, open element inspector and view childs of head tag. you can see 2 style tags. Now click on the link and a new style tag will be added. Navigating back should remove the child tag. another workaround is to use unique classnames for body and apply style to the classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem is.

Rails by default bundles [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks), which does not reload the `<head>` of a new page if you click a link, to make loading pages faster. So as I put my style tags within the `<head>` of the page, these attributes didn't change until you reloaded the page. The quick fix was to remove turbolinks, but in the long run I will probably try to reintroduce it but then properly configure my page to use it to my advantage.